# Can a folder of Google Drive be embedded on a Google Sites page?

Tags: google, google-drive, google-classic-sites

I have a Google Sites page and I need to share a folder to a group of people on the intranet. I couldn't find a way to do this way nor a way to do it file by file.

I do want to share a folder and its subfolders, with several files in them, and I don't want to do it manually one by one.

Can I embed the folder and the tree?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have found to do this is to add the link to the shared folder on your site. This will then open in a new browser tab. Not as good as the embedded, but it works.

I've tried using iframes with the folder url but they are blank - no idea why.

Answer (score -1):

I think that this tool can help you a lot http://www.evenbytes.com/metadrive.html

Metadrive will give you some extra nice functionalities like browsing by folder, search and custom metadata

Comment: Welcome to WebApps StackExchange! EvenBytes Metadrive solution for Google Drive looks promising. It would be helpful if you could specify whether it was a fee-based service, and designed for Google Apps users only. If so, that's okay, as the question says "intranet", but doesn't mention Google Apps. Also, additional details, specifically if Metadrive allows embedding on a Google Sites page, not merely shared access at a granular level, would be helpful